# Creating rtf template with multi spreadsheets(excel)

Tags: excel, report, rtf, oracle-bi, xdodtexe

I have created a data template report(`xdodtexe`) and the output will be in excel with multiple spread sheets. My **E-Business Suite** version is **`r12.1.3`** and I am using **Office 2013**.

I have created an `rtf` and in two separate pages layouts are there. For example department in page and employees in page. I am using `<?spreadsheet-sheet-name: department?>` for naming the sheets but the sheet name comes as "***`fndwrr`***" and both the outputs are in the same excel sheet without splitting into two different sheets.

I have also used `<?split-by-page-break:?>` for splitting into two sheets but this also does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Hello there fellow "BI Publisher self-torturer" :-),

First of all, I would suggest you go over this document [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10415_01/doc/bi.1013/e14667/create_excel_tmpl.htm#ext_multsheets), as the best method of manipulating `XLS` outputs is by using Excel templates.

Second of all - it would have been great if you supply a sample of the xml data + a sample of the template code as you have it.

Btw, the `split-by-page-break` that you're trying is for other output formats, such as `PDF`, `RTF` etc. which follow a paging rule, unlike `XLS`.
This being said - I am pretty sure you can't do that using an `RTF` template.

Also, you should mention the version of the XDO Engine/BI Publisher, because Excel templates are available since version 11.1.15 of BI Publisher.

Pay special attention to the following section **Table 3-2 Column Entries**, as you would need to put the `XDO_SHEET_?` and `XDO_SHEET_NAME_?`, the first being the split/group criteria and the second the actual name of the sheet.

Cheers